# Chosing the right test for weekly disease counts

Tags: stata, poisson-distribution, residuals, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I am using STATA to analyze count data (weekly disease counts), and I am trying to pick the best test between Poisson, negative binomial and zero-inflated Poisson / negative binomial but I am not sure how to do this.
My outcome variable has a variance that is much larger than the mean and contains a large number of zeros.

I've read a couple of articles mentioning that I should look at the predicted / actual residuals, but I don't know how to do it or what I should be looking for to pick the right test.

Comment: What do you actually want to test or rather what kind of model do you want to fit ? A GLM or GLMM, for example ? It sounds like you have zero inflated data, so a ZIP or ZINB might be appropriate. Can you post  histogram of the data ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have continuous and categorical predictors for the disease outcome and my outcome variable is over dispersed:

Comment: Is it overdispersed *and* zero-inflated ?

Comment: Thanks again, one last question: when I use zip in Stata, how do I know which variable I should use for the inflate() section of the code? Thanks!

Comment: `inflate()` is used to specify one or more predictors of the excess zeros. It is optional.   If my answer was useful, you can upvote it :)

Comment: ok, thank you! I'm new to stackexchange, so thanks for letting me know about upvoting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by fitting a zero-inflated poisson model and a zero inflated negative binomial model. The latter is particularly suited if your outcome data are overdispersed as well as zero inflated.

In Stata you can use `zip` and `zinb`, for example:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r10/fish, clear
zip count child camper, inflate(persons) vuong

webuse fish, clear
zinb count child i.camper, inflate(persons) vuong zip
```

You can compare models using AIC or BIC and by looking at their predictions.